# Why cannot I input a tex file to the main tex file?

Tags: input

I want to insert a old tex file to the new tex file which I'm currently working on,
I made it like this: [image]

however, it always has error, such as

> ./1.tex:1:LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.
>   [image]

The code in `main.tex` is

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \begin{document}
 1 
 \input{1} 
 \end{document}
```

The code in `1.tex` is

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
wangyan
\end{document}
```

what is wrong with it?

Comment: `input` basically copies the content of the file in your current file. You can't have two documentclasses and `\begin{document}` in a single document.

Comment: Thanks, when I　removed '\begin\end{document}' and `\documentclass{article}`, it works fine, but, I indeed want to emerge two  `\documentclass{article}` files, for example, one tex file is for a graph, how could I solve this problem?

Comment: Try `\usepackage{standalone}` in the main-file.

Comment: I personally would compile the graph and include the resulting pdf. The `standalone` class is great for that. EDIT: Or do what Ulrike says ;)

Comment: @ UlrikeFischer  I tried this in `main.tex` `\documentclass{standalone}
   \begin{document}
    1 
    \input{1} 
\end{document}`, same error.

Comment: You should read more carefully what I wrote: Load the *package* standalone, not the *class*.

Comment: @WangyanLi Don't forget to remove the `\end{document}` as well, otherwise the compilation stops prematurely.

Comment: @ulrike thx, I see

Comment: @1010011010 you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're inputting the entirety of `1.tex` into your main file; that means that your main file has two `\documentclass` commands and two `\begin{document}`/`\end{document}` commands, which it can't.

You're getting the error that `\documentclass` can only be in the preamble (that is, before `\begin{document}`) because you're inputting *after* `\begin{document}`.  (Though even in the preamble, you can still only have one `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`.)

Delete everything up through `\begin{document}` in `1.tex`, and also delete `\end{document}` in `1.tex` (unless that's really where you want your document to end), and you should get a clean compile.

EDIT:  Oops, while I was typing the comments cleared it up.  `standalone` should indeed help you.

EDIT AGAIN:  If you absolutely, positively need to keep the `\documentclass` and `begin{document}` and stuff in your included document, you don't need to change anything; just load (very early in your document) the `standalone` package.  This will give you a `main.tex` that looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
1 \input{1.tex}
\end{document}
```

And a `1.tex` that looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
included!
\end{document}
```

Running `pdflatex main.tex` compiles cleanly.

For future reference, you can always run `texdoc standalone` (or whatever the package or class name is) to get the documentation.  The documentation is also available on the CTAN website.

Comment: The `standalone` did not work, as you suggested, I have changed the code `1.tex` into  `\documentclass{standalone} 
    wangyan`, same error happened.

Comment: I think `standalone` should be in `main.tex`.

Comment: I have made `standalone` be in `main.tex`, nothing else changed, same error.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show the basic usage of `standalone`.  Hope that helps.